# Why is Bootcamp Assistant on my MacBook Pro (M2) after using Migration Assistant?

Tags: migration, intel, apple-m1, bootcamp

I have a question. I have purchased a new MacBook Pro 14" (M2 Silicon Chip). My old computer was a 2013 iMac (intel based). I used Apple's Migration Assistant to migrate the data from the older iMac (running Catalina 10.15.17) to my new MacBook.

While there were a few hiccups, most of the apps seem to be working fine. However, I am noticing that "Bootcamp Assistant" is now listed as a hidden app under the `/system/applications/utility folder`. I tried removing it manually via the UI and then using a linux terminal (`sudo -Rf "bootcamp utility.app"`), but it seems the file cannot be deleted.

I even went hard core and booted the new Macbook into recovery mode and used the `csrutil disable` command to disable the System Integrity Protection (SIP), but upon rebooting, I still was unable to delete the file.

Any advice? I don't like having phantom files like this kicking around, even if they are hidden. How did this happen? Is this a bug with Migration Assistant? Shouldn't MA have filtered this out as part of the migration?

Comment: You cannot modify anything under `/System`, and nothing there was migrated. The Boot Camp utility is there because Apple still ships it in macOS, because certain Intel Macs are still supported.

Comment: This sysadmin question belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.  It's not about programming.

Comment: Alright. I will post it under apple.stackexchange.com. Thanks Peter.